# use type: "POST" in a modal in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a modal in `codeigniter` is like a form, I can send the data to a especific `PHP` file here is the code:

```
$("#updateProvinciaBtn").click(function(){

            $(".control-group").fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
              myData=$("#updateform").serialize();
              console.log(myData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://site.com/uUser.php",
                data: myData,
                success: function(){
                    $('#updateUser').modal('hide');
                    window.location="http://site.com/index.php/zcms/users";                 
                }
            });// cierra ajax contactG  

        return true;


    });
```

All I want is change url: "http://site.com/uUser.php" for a script in my Model file in `codeigniter`
can I do that ?

This is my Uuser.php

```
include('openConn.php');

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$email_address=$_POST['email_address'];

mysql_query( "SET NAMES 'utf8' " );                 
$strSQL="UPDATE users SET ";
$strSQL.="first_name='".$first_name."', ";
$strSQL.="last_name='".$last_name."', ";
$strSQL.="username='".$username."', ";
$strSQL.="email_address='".$email_address."', ";
$strSQL.="id='".$id."' ";
$strSQL.="WHERE id=".$id;       
//echo $strSQL;
mysql_query($strSQL);
```

Comment: Did you read http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?

Comment: yes, but thats are Wildcards, this is my uUser.php code

Comment: include('openConn.php');

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$email_address=$_POST['email_address'];

mysql_query( "SET NAMES 'utf8' " );     
$strSQL="UPDATE users SET ";
$strSQL.="first_name='".$first_name."', ";
$strSQL.="last_name='".$last_name."', ";
$strSQL.="username='".$username."', ";
$strSQL.="email_address='".$email_address."', ";
$strSQL.="id='".$id."' ";
$strSQL.="WHERE id=".$id;  
//echo $strSQL;
mysql_query($strSQL);

Comment: Since you edited your question: What exactly do you want to do now? Send your data to another file and not just uUser.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is create a function in my controller

```
function uUser() {
        $this -> zcms_model -> uUser();
            }
```

then create a function in my model

```
public function uUser()
    {
        $data = array(
          'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
          'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),

        );
        $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('users',$data); 

    }
```

And is working, I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't reply to my comment:

In general: You can change the url in your javascript if you entered the url in your routes file(application/config/routes.php) and got the corresponding function ready(in your **controller**).

As I said, read [http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: sorry but i did respond you, but is not what iam looking for

Comment: Ok so please edit your question and explain a little more. You are sending your data from your website(using CodeIgniter) to another website, right? Or is it the same website? After you received the data, what do you want to do then? Pass the data to your model?